# WCF servicehost codebehind

Tags: wcf

I have a website project and in that I added a .svc file with the following details-

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="VB" Debug="true" Service="Communication" CodeBehind="???" %>
```

Here am not sure what should I put in for "CodeBehind". As I have put all my service contracts and their implementations in another project and I added that project as a reference to this website. Is this allowed? Or Do I need to have the Codebehind files only in the App_Code folder under website project?

Please suggest if there is a way to specify the CodeBehind file other than placing that in App_Code folder.

Thanks in advance 
Sai

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you don't need a codebehind I don't believe.  Just specifying the service is enough, although you need to specify the full namespace of the class which implements the service.

According to [this example](http://www.thatindigogirl.com/VS2008Beta2ProjectsWCFServiceApplication.aspx), you should be fine doing this if the class is in another referenced assembly, in which case you don't need the language bit either, only the service part.

In the [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx) they don't use it.

Comment: thanks for replying. if I dont specify code behind how will system know the implementation of the serviceContract? Can I specify that in the web.config file  ?

Comment: The service is the full name of actual implementation class not the interface of the service or the file containing the code I believe.